# Does amazon allow start on boot for fire tv stick apps?

Tags: amazon-fire-tv

Are Amazon fire TV stick apps allowed to start on boot? I did not find anything regarding this in Amazon's documentation.
If start on boot is not allowed, is delayed start allowed? How can I go about implementing this?

Comment: start on boot apps are not allowed.  Start on boot services are allowed.

Comment: Do you know where I can find more details on that? How can I implement services?

Comment: no.  I just know it can be done.  You can't boot directly on a fire tv to a specific app without root and some of their devices have never been rooted and others require soldering points on the circuit board.  Frankly i don't see why that's an issue since nobody ever turns them off anyway.  I have one service on mine that emulates a mouse from doubleclicking the select button.  Their OS is based on standard android.  I believe service creation is standard.  I've never actually programmed one myself so you would have better luck finding the info yourself.